# What impact will keeping the Senate but losing the House have on Trump's ability to implement his agenda?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

In the 2018 mid-term election, the Republicans lost the house but appear to have increased their majority in the Senate.

Will that give President Trump *more* power to implement his agenda (immigration, building the wall, etc.)? Or less? Or the same as before?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because speculation. We don't know what Trump's agenda will be in the future. If it is curtailing bureaucratic regulation and appointing judges, losing the House impacts it very little.

Comment: BradC's edit seems to have neutralized objectionable content in the question, the answers he's provided as a result seem unbiased and general enough to avoid speculation.

Answer (score 9):

- Trump will find it *more* difficult to do anything that requires *passing legislation*, which need the approval of both the House and Senate.
- Trump will find it *less* difficult to get his nominees for appointed positions approved, since they only require approval by the Senate. Prior to the election, Republicans had only a slim 51-49 majority, with a few moderate Republicans that were less willing to rubber-stamp his appointees.
- Trump will have *much more difficulty* dealing with US House committees run by Democrats, who will have the power to open investigations and issue subpoenas for documents and/or testimony concerning the myriad of scandals during Trump's administration.